# Replacing a symbol in a .txt file

Tags: recursion, replace, symbols

Alright, I've been given a program that requires me to take a .txt file of varying symbols in rows and columns that would look like this.

```
..........00
...0....0000
...000000000
0000.....000
............
..#########.
..#...#####.
......#####.
...00000....
```

and using command arguments to specify row and column, requires me to select a symbol and replace that symbol with an asterisk. The problem i have with this is that it then requires me to recur up, down, left, and right any of the same symbol and change those into an asterisk.
As i understand it, if i were to enter "1 2" into my argument list it would change the above text into.

```
**********00
***0....0000
***000000000
0000.....000
............
..#########.
..#...#####.
......#####.
...00000....
```

While selecting the specified character itself isn't a problem, how do i have any similar, adjacent symbols change and then the ones next to those. I have looked around but can't find any information and as my teacher has had a different subs for the last 3 weeks, i havent had a chance to clarify my questions with them. I've been told that recursion can be used, but my actual experience using recursion is limited. Any suggestions or links i can follow to get a better idea on what to do? Would it make sense to add a recursive method that takes the coordinates given adds and subtracts from the row and column respectively to check if the symbol is the same and repeats?

Answer (score 0):

Load in char by char, row by row, into a 2D array of characters. That'll make it a lot easier to move up and down and left and right, all you need to do is move one of the array indexes.

You can also take advantage of recursion. Make a function that changes all adjacent matching characters, and then call that same function on all adjacent matching characters.

Comment: so was i headed in the right direction by saying "Would it make sense to add a recursive method that takes the coordinates given adds and subtracts from the row and column respectively to check if the symbol is the same and repeats?"

Comment: Yea, definitely. Just be careful about how much you are adding or subtracting when you pass the values into the recursion part. I haven't thought it out completely, but maybe you want to call the function four times, left, right, up, down, by slightly changing (+/-1) one of the indexes that the parent had. And of course be sure not to run out of bounds of the array, whilst doing.